# Classes in JavaScript using prototype

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a problem, I want to create a JavaScript class:

```
function Calculatore(txt,elements) {
    this.p= new Processor();
    this.output=txt;
    $(elements).click(this.clickHandler);   

}
Calculatore.prototype.clickHandler = function() {
var element=$(this);

// Code Here

// "this" contains the element.
// But what if I want to get the "output" var?
// I tried with Calculatore.prototype.output but no luck.

}
```

So how can I solve this?

Answer (score 3):

You have a collision between `this` values. You currently don't have access to the instance because `this` has been set to the element inside a click handler.

You could make a proxy function to pass both the `this` value (the element) and the instance:

```
function Calculatore(txt,elements) {
    this.p= new Processor();
    this.output=txt;
    var inst = this; // copy instance, available as 'this' here

    $(elements).click(function(e) {
        return inst.clickHandler.call(this, e, inst); // call clickHandler with
                                                      // 'this' value and 'e'
                                                      // passed, and send 'inst'
                                                      // (the instance) as well.
                                                      // Also return the return
                                                      // value
    });

}

Calculatore.prototype.clickHandler = function(e, inst) {
    var element = $(this);

    var output = inst.output;
};
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use jQuery's `$.proxy`:

```
function Calculatore(txt,elements) {
    this.p= new Processor();
    this.output=txt;
    $(elements).click($.proxy(this.clickHandler, this));
}

Calculatore.prototype.clickHandler = function(event) {
    var clickedElement = event.target;
    alert(this.output);
}
```

Edited. Jason brought up a good point in the comments.  It's probably better to use `event.target` which references only the element clicked, rather than `elements` which may reference an array of objects matching the selection.

Comment: or use `event.target` instead of saving the elements (event is the first parameter in the clickHandler)

Comment: Note that event.target (which is W3C spec) is not IE compatible - You'll have to check event.srcElement as well.

Comment: @MikeChristensen, since the OP is using jQuery, the check is handled by the library. So, event.target will work for all browsers. https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/event.js#L540